# How to do batch Google DataStore key lookup query in JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo, gql, jdoql

I have about 50k entities stored in appengine.   I am able to look up an individual record via the GQL admin interface with a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM Pet where __key__ = KEY( 'Pet','Fido')
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to do a batch version of this via JDO.  Right now I have this:

```
    PersistenceManager pm = ...;
    for(Pet pet : pets) {
        for(String k : getAllAliases(pet)) {
            keys.add(KeyFactory.createKeyString(Pet.class.getSimpleName(), k));
        }
    }
    Query q = pm.newQuery("select from " + Pet.class.getName() + " where id == :keys");
    List<Pet> petlist = (List<Pet>) q.execute(keys);
```

But though 'Fido' works in the GQL case, it returns nothing when I use that Java + JDO code.   What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use queries to fetch entities by key - they're inefficient, and require a query for each object retrieved! Instead, [get the objects by key](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Getting_an_Object_By_Key). Bulk fetches by key don't appear to be supported by JDO, but fetching them by key one at a time is still going to be a lot more efficient than doing queries for them.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that fetching entities - synchronously - individually by key is going to be faster than doing a JDO query.  I will try the experiment at some point.

Comment: 'IN' is not natively supported by App Engine - the SDK emulates it by executing multiple, sequential, queries. Each query has to do an index scan followed by a lookup by key. In comparison, a lookup by key only has to do a small part of that, so it's substantially faster.

Answer (score 1):

Likely doesn't work in the JDOQL case since it isn't valid JDOQL :-P

```
Collection keys = ... (create your keys collection)
Query q = pm.newQuery("SELECT FROM " + Pet.class.getName() + " WHERE :keys.contains(id)");
```

i.e the filter uses Java syntax

Comment: Good to know.   I was expecting to get some sort of hard-to-ignore error notification if the query wasn't valid, so I'm disappointed there.

Answer (score 0):

http://gae-java-persistence.blogspot.com/2009/10/executing-batch-gets.html

I didn't try the JDO version, but the JPA version does work!